# Air-Filter Tag Used for Air and Cabin Filters

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

The [air-filter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-filter) is being used for both air filters and for cabin filters. My suggestion is to create the second tag for the cabin air filter as [cabin-filter](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cabin-filter) and separate out the questions into their respective tags. If this is done, I can update the tag wikis to reflect the correct usage. With most new cars coming with cabin air filters, this will become more pertinent going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create the new tag yourself. Just edit the tags on the question and create the new tag. Then edit the others that are miss tagged

Comment: I will try ... I couldn't remember when I could start adding my own tags, lol. Will handle it :D

Comment: I have made all of the changes. I believe about 1/2 of the questions fell in each category. They do need to be accepted as edits so they will become visible, and then I'll add context to the [tag:cabin-filter] tag.

Comment: Tags are at 150, edits are at 1000, so now your edits will be applied immediately!

Comment: Yup yup. Thanks Larry. Makes life a lot easier :D

Comment: HAHA! But tag edits do not appear directly yet (for some reason). Doesn't matter, I'll keep adding to them as I have time.